# DDD: Modeling Inbox and SentBox

Tags: domain-driven-design

We are creating an application for the domain of **Document management & tracking**. In this application **Document** is an aggregate. There is a pre-condition that an user can work on a document if it is available inside **his Inbox**, similarly he can perform some action on the Document in his **Sent Box**. We are thinking on how to model the **Inbox and Sent Box**. We also have an Aggregate named DocumentMovement.

```
 @Aggregate
 class DocumentMovement{
    MovementId id;
    User from;
    User to;
    Date movedOn;
    String remarks;
 }

@ValueObject
Class User{
    String userId;
}
```

Solution 1:
           We can model **Inbox and Sent Box** as Value Objects, as given below.

```
@ValueObject
enum State{
     INBOX, SENTBOX;
}

@Aggregate
class Document{
    DocumentId id;
    User currentlyWith;
    State currentState;
}
```

Solution 2: We could model the **Inbox and Sent Box** as aggregate themselves.

```
@Aggregate
class UserInbox {
   String userId;
   List<Document> documents;
   public void addDocument(Document doc);
   public void removeDocument(Document doc);
   public boolean isDocumentPresent(DocumentId doc);
}

@Aggregate
class UserSentBox {
   String userId;
   List<Document> documents;
   public void addDocument(Document doc);
   public boolean isDocumentPresent(DocumentId doc);
}
```

This model looks fine but worried about the performance of loading the complete SentBox just to check the document is present there.

Solution 3: We could model the **Inbox and SentBox** as Domain Services.

```
   interface UserInboxService {
      public boolean isDocumentPresent(DocumentId doc);
   }

   interface UserSentBoxService {
      public boolean isDocumentPresent(DocumentId doc);
   }
```

We would like to know which one out of these 3 solutions reflect the domain correctly or is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> "There is a pre-condition that an user can work on a document if it is
>   available inside his Inbox"

If "working" on a `Document` implies changing the state of the `Document` AR then having the inbox/sentbox state within the `Document` boundary is the only design that allows you to protect that invariant in a strongly consistent manner, without modifying more than one AR per transaction.